# How can we create a partial read-only textbox in windows forms c#?

Tags: windows, forms, textbox

I want to get details of the names where their surname is fixed(readonly) in the textbox and original name should be typed from the user end....Is there anyway to make it in windows forms...Please help me I would be really thankful.

Answer (score 0):

Make two textboxes.

Set the ReadOnly property to true for one of them.